# Modify a data frame converting colnames into factor

Tags: r

I´m analyzing some data structured as "df" in the example and I need to convert it into something like the "example" object below:

```
a<- c(1:3)
b<- c(1:3)
c<- c(1:3)

df<- data.frame(a, b, c)

col1<- c("a","a","a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
col2<- rep(1:3,3)

example<- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything())
```

Comment: This works great!
Some issues:
- I have multiple column so i have to exclude some of them with the parameter col= - col to exclude.
- I have to use the lastest version of tidyr

Comment: @federicofookes yes, please do mention the issues. thanks

Comment: Just this 2. I have to reinstall tidyr to get the lastest version, in older one pivot_longer is not available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick `base R` solution is `stack`:

```
stack(df)
  values ind
1      1   a
2      2   a
3      3   a
4      1   b
5      2   b
6      3   b
7      1   c
8      2   c
9      3   c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `gather()` from `tidyr` package

```
gather(df, colnames(df), key = "col1", value = "col2")
```

`key` and `value` serves as new column names in the resulting dataframe. Use in `tidyverse` syntax as follows

```
df %>%
   gather(colnames(df), key = "col1", value = "col2")
```